# Jhipster Minimum and Maximum Validation is not working

Tags: jhipster

Validation is not working as expected.
I have selected an integer with minimum 6 and maximum 6 for postal code.
But, it is not working as expected.  Same with other fields where min and max is same.

Is any one having any solutions... or shall we forward it to Jhipster Team.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Vc7.png)

Comment: Please add a code snippet with your code, so that people can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Min/Max validation for Integers is based on the number value, not length.

I recommend using a String for these fields, as they may begin with a leading zero.  Otherwise you can add the length validation manually, as JHipster does not support generating length validation on Integers.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes..I  have changed it to string and it is working as expected.. :)